How to ingest Elasticsearch data and convert it to SQL tables using Apache Nifi?
I'm an intern tasked with finding a workaround for the limitations of the Elasticsearch SQL API. Specifically, I need to create a process that converts data from Elasticsearch into a SQL format using Apache NiFi. The SQL output will then be used to create dashboards in Apache Superset, avoiding the limitations of the Elasticsearch SQL API.
Here's what I need to accomplish:
-Extract data from Elasticsearch.
-Transform the extracted data into SQL format.
-Load the SQL data into a database that can be used by Apache Superset for dashboard creation.
I've searched online with various keywords but haven't found a clear solution. Is it even possible to achieve this with NiFi? If so, could someone guide me through the process or point me to relevant resources?
Thank you in advance!
